# How to get default browser name using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, browser, windows-10

Following solutions (actually it is only one) doesn't work to me :

> [How to get a name of default browser using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037216/how-to-get-a-name-of-default-browser-using-python)

---

> [How to get name of the default browser in windows using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681951/how-to-get-name-of-the-default-browser-in-windows-using-python)

Solution was:

```
from _winreg import HKEY_CURRENT_USER, OpenKey, QueryValue
# In Py3, this module is called winreg without the underscore

with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
             r"Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command") as key:
    cmd = QueryValue(key, None)
```

But unfortunately, in Windows 10 Pro I don't have targeted registry value. I've tried to find alternative keys in Regedit, but no luck.

Please take a look, what my registry virtually contains:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me on Windows 10 pro:

```
from winreg import HKEY_CURRENT_USER, OpenKey, QueryValueEx

reg_path = r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice'

with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_path) as key:
    print(QueryValueEx(key, 'ProgId'))
```

Result (first with Chrome set as default, then with IE):

```
$ python test.py
('ChromeHTML', 1)

$ python test.py
('IE.HTTPS', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the key in windows 10

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\URLAssociations(http|https)\UserChoice

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_windows_default_browser_launch():
    """ On windows, return the default browser for 'https' urls
    returns: example '"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -osint -url "%1"'
    """
    import winreg
    key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER), r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice")
    prog_id, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "ProgId")
    key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), r"SOFTWARE\Classes\{}\shell\open\command".format(prog_id))
    launch_string, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "")  # read the default value
    return launch_string
```

Windows 10 Python3 , may want to change the key for 'http' not https, but this is my code verbatim as my context is of a secured server. I wanted the browser binary name and path, which is just one more line.