# Is there a way to get the default browser in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I want a way to find the default browser in Python. I've seen https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/webbrowser.html
and there might be a way of converting a webbrowser instance which I do not know.

Does anybody know how I could go about doing that?

Also, I'm using Windows - it doesn't need to work for Mac or Ubuntu.

Edit:

I've already tried [this website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681951/how-to-get-name-of-the-default-browser-in-windows-using-python) and it gives me an error saying that 'the file path does not exist'.

Additionally, I don't want to open a tab in the default browser, I just want the name.

Edit #2:

The following code works but returns Internet Explorer instead of my actual default which is Chrome.

```py
from winreg import*
with OpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,r"http\\shell\\open\\command") as key:
    cmd = QueryValue(key, None)
```

Comment: Does this fit you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037216/how-to-get-a-name-of-default-browser-using-python

Comment: @Chris That returns an error saying the file path does not exist.

Comment: Here is a more indepth article: https://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get name of the default browser in windows using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681951/how-to-get-name-of-the-default-browser-in-windows-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. I'm pretty sure this only works on Windows, but here's the code:

```py
from winreg import *
with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Shell\\Associations\\UrlAssociations\\http\\UserChoice") as key:
    browser = QueryValueEx(key, 'Progid')[0]
```

It will return `ChromeHTML` for Chrome, `FirefoxURL` for Firefox, and `IE.HTTP` for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```py
import webbrowser

default_browser = webbrowser.get()

default_browser_name = default_browser.name
default_browser_basename = default_browser.basename
```

As the docs say

> `webbrowser.get([name])`
>
> Return a controller object for the browser type name. If name is empty, return a controller for a default browser appropriate to the caller’s environment.

Comment: Sorry, that just returns an empty string.

Comment: I see. Works on linux, didn’t have a Windows to test on